# How to test the run time performance of a code with specified computing power

Tags: algorithm, performance, testing, operating-system, runtime

How can I ensure a fair comparison of algorithm performance, particularly in terms of runtime, for my academic research? I aim to conduct tests on several algorithms, and to maintain consistency, I intend to execute them with predefined computing resources (CPU and memory) to include in my research paper. Are there established practices or norms for such comparisons in academic settings? Additionally, are there specific command-line tools available for this purpose, or should I manually control resource allocation by minimizing background processes while timing the algorithms?

Edit 1: the code was written in Python.

Comment: It would help to add language and platform in to the questions. Approaches could be quite different for C or JS or Arduino